# about finite group with order $100$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples

let $G$ be a finite group with order $100$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with order $25$ also let $a \in G$ has order $50$. Now which of following options is true?

1)$\quad$ $|\langle a \rangle H |=50$

2)$\quad a \in H$

3)$\quad G \cong H \times \langle a^2 \rangle$

4)$\quad \langle a \rangle H=G$

> let $G =\Bbb Z_{25}\times \Bbb Z_{4}$ and $a=(1,2)$ and $H=\langle (1,0) \rangle $ then 2 is wrong. Also 3 is wrong because $\langle a^2 \rangle \subset H$

Comment: How could $a$ be in $H$?  A group of order $25$ can't contain an element of order $50$.

Comment: @lulu .i edited.

Comment: More broadly, suppose $H=<a^2>$.  That eliminates $3$ of your cases right off.  Of course, you should still confirm that the remaining case is always true (it is certainly true in this particular case, of course).

Comment: Brief tex-y note: we can typeset $H = \langle a^2 \rangle$ (which looks much nicer than the version using < and >) with `H = \langle a^2 \rangle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H$ is a $5$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.  By Sylow’s Theorem, $H$ is normal in $G$, and hence is the unique subgroup of order $25$.  Since $\vert \langle a^2 \rangle \vert =25,$ we have $\langle a^2 \rangle = H \leq \langle a \rangle$.  Thus, $\langle a \rangle H=\langle a \rangle$, which has order $50$.  Therefore, $1$ is true and the rest are false.

Answer (score 1):

$|\langle a\rangle \cap H|$ has order $1,5$ or $25$.

$\langle a\rangle $ is normal. By the second isomorphism theorem,  $\langle a\rangle H$ is a subgroup,
and  $\langle a\rangle H/\langle a\rangle \cong H/H\cap\langle a\rangle $.

Now, we can't have $H\cap\langle a\rangle =e$, because then $|H\langle a\rangle|=|H|\cdot|\langle a\rangle |=25\cdot 50$.

Similarly we can't have $|H\cap\langle a\rangle |=5$.  Thus $H\le\langle a\rangle $.

Thus $|H\langle a\rangle |=50$.

Thus $1)$ is true.